# How to do rolling `get_dummies` for each group of a groupby - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, data-science

I have a dataframe like below

```
   A             B          
Customer_1    1000      
Customer_1    2000      
Customer_1    3000      
Customer_2    2000      
Customer_2    3000      
Customer_3    1000      
Customer_3    3000
```

I want to transform the above dataframe like below , how can i make it ?

```
A             B           3000      2000    1000
Customer_1    1000         0         0       1
Customer_1    2000         0         1       1
Customer_1    3000         1         1       1
Customer_2    2000         0         1       0
Customer_2    3000         1         1       0
Customer_3    1000         0         0       1
Customer_3    3000         1         0       1
```

I cant figure out how to do this,please help me on this and let me know if you need clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_dummies`, of the `str` accessor, also use `join` to merge:

```
print(df.join(df.B.astype(str).str.get_dummies()))
```

Output:

```
            A     B  1000  2000  3000
0  Customer_1  1000     1     0     0
1  Customer_1  2000     0     1     0
2  Customer_1  3000     0     0     1
3  Customer_2  2000     0     1     0
4  Customer_2  3000     0     0     1
5  Customer_3  1000     1     0     0
6  Customer_3  3000     0     0     1
```

It's really just merging `df` with that value with `0`, `1`, how the `0`, `1` is done? use `get_dummies` which does it all by itself.

**Edit:**

```
print(df.join(df.join(df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x['B'].astype(str).str.get_dummies()).fillna(0).astype(int)).groupby('A').cumsum().drop('B',1)))
```

Output:

```
            A     B  1000  2000  3000
0  Customer_1  1000     1     0     0
1  Customer_1  2000     1     1     0
2  Customer_1  3000     1     1     1
3  Customer_2  2000     0     1     0
4  Customer_2  3000     0     1     1
5  Customer_3  1000     1     0     0
6  Customer_3  3000     1     0     1
```

Comment: this is not what i needed , pls look the requirement once again.

Comment: @ramesh What's the difference?

Comment: Can you explain the logic perhaps?

Comment: @yatu Now? enough?

Comment: Enough? You haven't added anything

Comment: for customer_1 if i have B column with 1000, 2000 ,3000 then the for customer1 with 3000 row ,should have column values with 1 1 1 for 3000 , 2000 ,1000 .please look at the output which i posted in the question one more time

Comment: @ramesh Oh.. that's right.

Comment: @ramesh I'll edit my answer in like 15~20 hours, i have to go somewhere a little and then sleep.

Comment: @ramesh I can edit now.

Comment: @U9-Forward , thanks

Comment: @ramesh Don't forget to accept my answer if it works :-), happy to help, :-)

Comment: @U9-Forward, i  have other question as well, i which needs a solution  will post the question url here,pleasee help me out on that as well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54152104/pandas-get-rolling-data-of-past-years-for-the-current-year-row

Comment: kindly look above url and help me with a solution

Comment: @ramesh Ya deleted it, so?